# Why aren't this two methods giving the same result?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, exponential-distribution

> Given two random variables $X_1\sim\text{Exp}(\lambda_1)$, $X_2\sim\text{Exp}(\lambda_2)$ find
>   $$\mathbb P(X_1<X_2\,\vert\,X_1>a)$$
>   where $a\geq0$.

Clearly one may use the memoryless property and only compute $\mathbb P(X_1<X_2)=\lambda_1/(\lambda_1+\lambda_2)$, but suppose I wanted to use the conditional definition, then
$$\mathbb P(X_1<X_2\,\vert\,X_1>a)= \frac{\mathbb P(a<X_1<X_2)}{\mathbb P(\,X_1>a)}=e^{a\lambda_1}\int_a^\infty\int_{x_1}^\infty\lambda_1\lambda_2e^{-(\lambda_1x_1+\lambda_2x_2)}dx_2dx_1=\frac{\lambda_1}{\lambda_1+\lambda_2}e^{-\lambda_2a}$$
which doesn't agree with the initial answer. What is wrong?

Comment: The memoryless property tells you $\mathbb{P)(X_1 > a+b|X_1 > a) = P(X_1>b)$, but it does not seem to work here.

Comment: Why should $P(X_1<X_2)$ be the same as $P(X_1<X_2|X_1 >a)$?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy that is what I read on the solution of the problem, that's why I was confused

Comment: You must mention that $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the memoryless property to "cut away" everything less than $a$ ignores the possibility that $X_2<a$. If we had had
$$
P(X_1<X_2\mid X_1>a, X_2>a)
$$
then the memoryless approach would've worked. But that's not what we are asked for.